# the_post_thumbnail Works everywhere except WooCommere pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm displaying entries pulled from a custom post type in a sidebar. This works fine, but while testing WooCommerce I notice the sidebar images don't show on WooCommerce product pages (they show fine on the main shop page). The other elements (link, title) work fine everywhere, including WooCommerce product pages.

Here's my sidebar:

```
<?php
$sidebarproxypost = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'cpt_proxies',
    'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
        
    while ($sidebarproxypost->have_posts() ) : $sidebarproxypost->the_post(); ?>
            
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-item list-item grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
                    
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
                    
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <?php the_title('<h4>','</h4>') ?>
            </div>
        </a>
        
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

In the HTML, no image tag is shown on affected pages. What have I missed?

Comment: Did you add `wp_reset_postdata()` after the `endwhile` of your custom loop?

Comment: I hadn't, but I've just added it and it makes no difference.